# Colibri opens instead of PDF and image files

Tags: 18.04, pdf, default-programs, jpeg

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, and some files no longer open correctly in their default applications (e.g. PDF and JPG files). Instead, Colibri opens with no content. I've confirmed their default application is set correctly (Document viewer for PDFs and Shotwell Viewer for JPGs) but they still open in Colibri. I can select 'open with' and choose the default application again, and they will open correctly.

I also found [Clicking links in pdfs opened with Okular opens Abiword (instead of the default browser)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160918/clicking-links-in-pdfs-opened-with-okular-opens-abiword-instead-of-the-default) whih looked similar and ran `kcmshell5 filetypes` but everything seemed to be normal.

From [command line - Open files only opens terminal instead of file browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922921/open-files-only-opens-terminal-instead-of-file-browser) I could check other mime-types, but I'm not sure what to look for.

What settings should I check for this default program problem?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: @DKBose it was available in terminal via tab completion, so I figured I'd take a look.

Comment: @Bruni It looks like I'm on GNOME 3.28.2

Comment: `kcmshell5` is provided by `kde-cli-tools` which is installed if you installed any of the following: `kdeconnect`, `plasma-workspace`, `plasma-desktop`, `kubuntu-full`, `kubuntu-desktop`, or `kscreen`.

Comment: I resolved my issue by removing Colibri from my system. It wasn't showing up as an apt package, which I thought was weird, but I removed it from the software manager, and PDFs and JPGs now open as expected

Answer (score 0):

#### Repair PDF opening in KDE

follow this guide:

https://www.ryananddebi.com/2014/09/29/linux-fixing-pdfs-opening-in-gimp-in-firefoxzotero/

basically edit (or create if not exists):

```
SUDO_EDITOR=kate sudoedit /usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

and add this block:

```
[Default Applications]
application/pdf=okularApplication_pdf.desktop
```